# C# winform identify mouse click by bots

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I have a C# winform application.

Is there a way to identify mouse click by bots (automated software).
I have to stop mouse clicks by bots using my software.

Comment: Why do you put c++ tag if this has nothing to do with c++?

Comment: Only by behavior pattern. E.g. you could try and detect clicks that happen too fast or too frequently.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani if someone knows a way to do it in c++ , that can give me some idea to do it c# as well

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to my problem for windows 8 and above

GetCurrentInputMessageSource function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448793.aspx

if originId is IMO_INJECTED, the input is emulated. Otherwise, it usually equals IMO_HARDWARE.

Comment: What happens, if an *"application [has] the UIAccess attribute set to TRUE in its manifest"*?

Comment: in my case the bot application was running with           <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/> , for an application to set uiAccess to “true" it also needs to set level=“asInvoker”, so i am not sure for the case in which the application  UIAccess attribute set to TRUE.